# How to set static port for RMI RenewClean Thread

Tags: rmi

Every time i re start my application RMI RenewClean Thread listens on dynamic port , below is my Thread stack trace

```
"RMI RenewClean-[10.58.121.180:16406]" Id=23 in TIMED_WAITING on lock=java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@6ab17e0a
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.DGCClient$EndpointEntry$RenewCleanThread.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export your remote object on a fixed port.

Comment: I have already have static port for rmiregistry, how to export remote object on fixed port

Comment: @user737936 super(port) if you extend UnicastRemoteObject, otherwise exportObject(object, port).